# How to solve isssue of Required: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment in a read only fragment

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-fragments, androidx

**What I have done:**

- I'm using [this](https://github.com/ShimmerEngineering/ShimmerAndroidAPI) library and imported via gradle. No issues when importing.
- I'm trying to use it's one of the fragments.

**Issue:**

- When I return a fragment, it says 
  [Incompatible types. Required: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM0Cz.png)

**Attempts to solve:**

- Tried suggesting refactoring but ended up receiving message due to "read-only" property of the provided fragment it cannot be done. ([image: error])

Any idea to get rid of this error please? Why this is happening?

~Thank you~

**Gradle file :**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url  "http://dl.bintray.com/shimmerengineering/Shimmer"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver:ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver:AA-227-1test'
}
```

**gradle.properties file:**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: if your project doesn't use androidx try `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` from the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you @MohammedAlaa, I tried this and replied in the discussion below. Seems like the working project is already with androix but the imported library is not and by trying `Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX` only the project affect but not the library.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at the code [here](https://github.com/nightscape/ShimmerAndroidAPI/blob/8e980760035206d3c593c0a2879ba91eda5245b5/ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver/shimmerServiceExample/src/main/java/com/shimmerresearch/shimmerserviceexample/MainActivity.java), it looks like they haven't updated to androidx yet and are still using v4 support library `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Since you have `android.enableJetifier=true` in your gradle properties, you should be able to just add the fragment library in your gradle file:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0'
```

And this would be the correct import in your class:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
```

If that doesn't work, try also adding (to gradle): `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'`  as is done [here](https://github.com/ShimmerEngineering/ShimmerAndroidAPI/blob/master/ShimmerAndroidInstrumentDriver/shimmerServiceExample/build.gradle) and use `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` in your class until they migrate to API 29 and androidx as well.

Comment: Thank you..., I added {implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'} to gradle since it showed that 'compile' is obsolete. After updating gradle it suggested to do Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX and I did it. Then the red underline was vanished. After in the main activity I commented {//import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;} and added as you suggested {import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;}. But seems like no luck... Here the word "Fragment" is red.

Comment: ```androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4``` is not the same as ```com.android.support:support-v4```, but nevermind that - see updated answer

Comment: thanks for the directions. I tried both the options, 1 - didn't work. 2 - when updating the gradle it was synched with this comment`//noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` , after adding `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` observed the same red underline for 'Fragment' which indicates not working. well.. maybe i could try creating fragment classes in andoridx instead

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using hasn't moved to AndroidX. Therefore you must [enable Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#migrate_an_existing_project_using_android_studio) on your project - this automatically transforms non-AndroidX projects into AndroidX projects, allowing you to use the `SignalsToPlotFragment` as if it *was* an `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

You want to add the following lines to your [gradle.properties file](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#properties-files), creating the file if it doesn't already exist:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: Since the source code is available, refactoring the library would also be an option.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - if you can get them to agree to the refactoring and publish a new version, sure. The whole point of Jetifier is that you don't need to wait for libraries to do that.

Comment: Whenever I intend to use something and it's on GitHub, I'll refactor and then PR; sure it depends on the effort involved, if it's really worth it - or if the Jetifier makes more sense.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - yeah, no reason to not do both (using Jetifier as a stop gap) if you have the time.

Comment: I merely do so, when a project appears abandoned - so that people can at least find the PR.

Comment: @ianhanniballake thank you for the direction. I found the gradle.propertise file and then I observed that suggested lines are already there. Now I updated the question with that file too.

Comment: @MohammedAlaa thank you for the suggestion. I tried this too and after making a backup it shows me a message as "No usages found in the project". But I was in the main activity where I used fragments (ex: SignalsToPlotFragment ) from the library and my main activity is red showing the mentioned error. I'm wondering why this is happening...